# Dúvida com Formatação de datas no sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

Na minha aplicação eu estou gravando as datas neste formato:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

No banco de dados eu tenho:  `2016-01-09 00:00:00.000`

Agora eu preciso fazer uma consulta onde vou trazer apenas os registros do dia.

```
select * from TB_JOGO where DATA_INC = CONVERT(datetime, DATA_INC)
```

Usando uma data fixa vai me trazer este resultado:

```
select  CONVERT(datetime, '2016-01-09')
```

> Resultado :   2016-01-09 00:00:00.000

Usando o getdate vai me trazer este resultado:

```
select  CONVERT(datetime, getdate())
```

> resultado:  2016-01-10 21:57:45.603

Eu preciso da data do dia neste formato : `2016-01-09 00:00:00.000` usando comando `getdate()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta assim:

```
select cast(getdate() as date) data
```

ou

```
select  CONVERT(date, getdate()) data
```

> data
>   ----------  
> 2016-01-10
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> data
>   ----------  
> 2016-01-10
>
> (1 row(s) affected)

Comment: Resposta certa, imensamente agradecido.